# Print list/array in columns

Tags: shell, fish

I have list/array, for example the $PATH env variable, when you do `echo $PATH` it prints

```
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin /usr/texbin /usr/local/go/bin
```

I would like this to be formatted in columns like below, so don’t have to scroll up down much. The `$PATH` variable is just an example, I would like to way to be able to do it with any list.

```
/usr/local/bin /usr/sbin    /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
/usr/bin       /sbin        /usr/texbin
/bin           /opt/X11/bin /usr/local/go/bin
```

I can print each item in the list in new row using a for loop but can’t figure out a way to do multiple columns. I know there is a column command but that doesn’t seem to do any thing. I’ve tried all the options like `echo $PATH | column -c 5`

Comment: That's not what `echo $PATH` gets you. And the list of commands isn't at all related to what `echo $PATH` gets you. I'm confused. You want to print a display of some set of values in nicely formatted columns?

Comment: @EtanReisner: it is what you get if you `echo $PATH` on the fish shell.

Comment: @cdarke Ah. Fair enough. I missed the `fish` tag there at the end.

Comment: @EtanReisner The list of commands was just an example of the format I would like, I’ve removed and replaced it with the real output I would like. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: pass in a variable *name* and the number of columns you want

```
$ function columnize -a listvarname -a ncols
      test (count $ncols) -eq 1; or set ncols 1
      printf "%s\n" $$listvarname | \
      eval paste (yes - | head -n $ncols | tr '\n' " ") | \
      column -t
  end
```

A demo using a non-special list name.

```
$ set list /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin /usr/texbin /usr/local/go/bin

$ columnize list 3
/usr/local/bin          /usr/bin     /bin
/usr/sbin               /sbin        /opt/X11/bin
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin  /usr/texbin  /usr/local/go/bin

$ columnize list 5
/usr/local/bin  /usr/bin                /bin         /usr/sbin          /sbin
/opt/X11/bin    /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin  /usr/texbin  /usr/local/go/bin

$ columnize list 
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
/usr/texbin
/usr/local/go/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $PATH|sed 's/ /\
/g'|column -xt -c5
```

Note:  after the \ make sure there follows a new-line

Comment: This just prints the output in one column and multiple rows, which I could have done with a for loop. Thanks anyway, this seems faster than iterating through a list.